# Move embedded programming from Keil to Linux

Tags: stm32, linux, gcc, keil

I'm currently using Keil to develop for an STM32 discovery board. My project is close to finished, and I'd like to move to a Linux based building environment. I've been using the preconfigured flashing tool and the STLink drivers for windows to flash the board, and I got keil to export a bin file, which I managed to flash on my Linux machine using [qSTLink2](https://code.google.com/p/qstlink2/). So far, so good.

Now I'm stuck on moving the process of building the entire project. Specifically:

How do I port my .uvproj to a makefile, while taking things like the 'startup_stm32l1xx_md.s' startup file into account?

Comment: I haven't used in an STM32 in particular under a Linux GCC build environment, but you'll probably find GCC needs a different startup file. You might be best to find an already working simple project and then add your code to that.

Comment: The hard way, no doubt.

Comment: Could I use the current .o file Keil generated using MDK-ARM, ignore the compilation for that one file for now, and link it in statically?

Comment: As PeterJ already wrote. It will use a different startup file with different labels and different semantics. There should be no way to keep the Keil startup_stm32l1xx_md.o file. Don't you have the source startup_stm32l1xx_md.s for it?

Comment: I do, but it seems oriented at MDK-ARM (or so the header claims). I've replaced it with [another](https://github.com/uctools/stm32l1xx-template/blob/master/src/startup_stm32l1xx_md.s). I'm not sure what the distinction between medium and high density entails, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it done. I figured I'd share my results so others can use it. Thanks for your time, everyone.

---

I used [this ARM toolchain](https://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/gcc-arm-embedded) to build my project, and the [texane/stlink](https://github.com/texane/stlink) library, which comes with the `./st-flash` tool, to flash the binary to my STM32L1. While texane/stlink comes with GDB, I found I could get the building+flashing process done without it.

My Makefile ended up looking like this. It isn't very pretty or abstract, but it gets the job done.

```
all:
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -T stm32l1xx.ld -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -D STM32L1XX_MD -D USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER startup_stm32l1xx_md.s system_stm32l1xx.c main.c [ sources ] -lm --specs=nosys.specs -o Project.elf
```

In which:

- `arm-none-eabi-gcc`
  The ARM toolchain
- `-T stm32l1xx.ld`
  The linker document
- `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3`
  Tell GCC this is for an M3
- `-D STM32L1XX_MD -D USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER`
  Defines for the Standard Peripheral Driver
- `startup_stm32l1xx_md.s`
  GCC oriented startup document.
- `system_stm32l1xx.c main.c [ sources ]`
  List of my source files
- `-lm`
  For `Math.h`(**L**ib**M**ath)
- `--specs=nosys.specs`
  Don't use sytems calls like `_exit`.
- `-o Project.elf`
  Output name

Comment: Where does the `stm32l1xx.ld` file come from?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Gnu ARM toolchain (arm-none-eabi), and supposedly openOCD works with gdb (although I haven't been able to make that happen under Win7 - openOCD connects to an STM32F4disco board OK, but gdb has problems connecting to openOCD).

Do some digging around [here](http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/) and you will find links to the toolchain, openOCD and sample projects that include startup source.